# Java - How to assign variables within evaluations?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a Java method `close()` which closes object if it is open, and which returns true if the action succeeded.

```
public boolean close() {
        if (open) {
            open = false;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to find a way to write this down with less code. What I came up with is the following.

```
public boolean close() {
        return (open && (open = false));
    }
```

Eclipse doesn't give any errors when I write this down. The left hand side of the evaluation checks if open is true, and if so, the right hand side should set open to false and return true as well.

I've tested the code, and open does get set to false, but it doesn't return true. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: `return (open && !(open = false))` if you really want to; but you're better off with the `if` statement, which makes sense to a reader.

Comment: You don't do it that way. Assigning values within expressions is bad practice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527575/is-there-a-post-assignment-operator-for-a-boolean

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like:

```
public boolean close () {
    return open != (open = false);
}
```

but if I was reviewing this code I would reject it as **unclear**.

I would probably do it using maximal clarity as:

```
public boolean close () {
    boolean wasOpen = open;
    open = false;
    return wasOpen;
}
```

and let the compiler optimise.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Because it can be done with **full** clarity in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it without conditional execution by preparing the return value before the assignment of `false`, like this:

```
boolean wasOpen = open;
open = false;
return wasOpen;
```

Comment: I promise I didn't see this before I edited mine.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I have no doubt about that :-) This is so simple that it's easy to see how multiple people could come up with the same solution, down to the naming of variables. I like your first solution, too (as you can probably see from my comment).

Comment: Second place for shortness but first place for clarity. I would definitely use this.

Answer (score 1):

```
return open ? !(open = false) : open;
```

or

```
return open ? !(open = false) : false;
```

Though, I don't like the idea of making the first snippet shorter. You are killing readability where it's already absent.

Personally, I would go with the original method introducing a local variable `wasOpen` as @dasblinkenlight suggested.

Comment: First place for shortness but not for clarity (see @dasblinkenlight).

Answer (score 0):

Not really, the assignment is evaluated prior to the rest of the expression, so what you're essentially saying is:

```
true && false
```

Also known as `false`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public boolean close() 
{     return !open = (open == true) ? false: true; }
```

Comment: *and which returns true if the action succeeded* - I think this would not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression  will evaluated as the following `true && false`,so the result is `false`

```
public boolean close() {
    if(!open) return open;
    open=false;
    return true;
}
```